# Cannot import python module from multiple level parent folder

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

I am running python 3.9. Here is my files:

- `pycharm_project/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/run.py`
- `pycharm_project/some_module.py`
- `pycharm_project/__init__.py`

```
pycharm_project
└── folder1
    ├── folder2
    │   └── folder3
    │       └── folder4
    │           └── run.py
    ├── some_module.py
    └── __init__.py
```

`some_module.py` contains the following code:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'This is A'
```

file `run.py` contains this import:

```py
from folder1.some_module import MyClass
```

When I launch `run.py` it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'some_module'`
But it's ok when I launch it via 'run' button in Pycharm.

I also tried to add this code but got the same error

```py
import sys
import os

current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

folder1_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(current_path))

sys.path.append(folder1_path)
from folder1.some_module import MyClass
```

Comment: You can use the PYTHONPATH environment variable to specify where python should look for libraries. I'm not familiar with pycharm but it probably adds the root directory to the pythonpath environment variable when it runs. If you are running code outside pycharm, you can do the same manually. I typically create a script which I run starting a console which activates the required environment, and adds any library locations to the PYTHONPATH variable.